# Concurrency control is not working

Tags: spring-security

We are migrating from Spring Security 2.0 to 3.1.

In Spring Security 2.0 the concurrency control was configured adding the following line in the configuration file:

```
<concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" />
```

Now, with 3.1, we added the following:

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/index.jsf">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
</session-management>
```

We make the login from a backing bean. The code is the following:

```
public String login(){
    Authentication authenticationResponseToken = authenticate();
    if (authenticationResponseToken != null && authenticationResponseToken.isAuthenticated()) {
        return NavigationConstants.PORTAL_REDIRECT_USER;
    }
    else{
        return NavigationConstants.PORTAL_LOGIN + sessionManagedBean.getUrlQuery();
    }
}

private Authentication authenticate(){
    debug("authenticate");
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = (AuthenticationManager) UtilidadesFaces.getSpringBean("authManager");
    //simple token holder
    Authentication authenticationRequestToken = createAuthenticationToken(sessionManagedBean);
    Authentication authenticationResponseToken = null;
    //authentication action
    try {
        authenticationResponseToken = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequestToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) authenticationResponseToken.getAuthorities();
        if(authorities.size() > 0){
            this.sessionManagedBean.setRole(authorities.get(0).getAuthority());
        }
        CustomUser customUser = (CustomUser) authenticationResponseToken.getPrincipal();
        this.sessionManagedBean.setIdCl(customUser.getIdCl());
    } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.badCredentialsException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    } catch (AuthenticationServiceException badCredentialsException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.badCredentialsException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    } catch (LockedException lockedException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.lockedException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.disabledException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    }

    return authenticationResponseToken;
}

private Authentication createAuthenticationToken(SessionManagedBean sessionManagedBean) {
    String username = sessionManagedBean.getUsername() + sessionManagedBean.getIdGuest();
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, sessionManagedBean.getPassword());
    return usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
}
```

We already have implemented the equals() and hashCode() methods in the class which implements UserDetails.

No concurrency control is working now, one user can login several times and work with all the sessions simoultaneously.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am using spring 3.2.1 , i just did the following

`// spring will inject ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy by default
@Autowired
SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy;`

and inside your authentication method i just called

sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken, httpReq, httpResp);

And in security.xml file

```
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login.jsp?time=1">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/logout"/>
    </session-management>
```

As all these are default values i think we dont need to set it.

This did the work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..according to me its work

```
<session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/loginexpired" />
         </session-management>
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, thank you for your response. Unfortunately it doesn´t work for me. I need to copy the existing session attributes to the new session, so i think i have to use session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" (default option). Besides, i need a second login will cause the first to be invalidated, not to prevent a second login.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved the issue calling SessionAuthenticationStrategy#onAuthentication and adding some spring security filters.

My code:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
    <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/index.jsf" />
    ......
    <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
    <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/index.jsf" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

....
```

and adding sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication()...

```
private Authentication authenticate(){
    debug("authenticate");
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = (AuthenticationManager) UtilidadesFaces.getSpringBean("authManager");
    //simple token holder
    Authentication authenticationRequestToken = createAuthenticationToken(sessionManagedBean);
    Authentication authenticationResponseToken = null;
    //authentication action
    try {
        authenticationResponseToken = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationRequestToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) authenticationResponseToken.getAuthorities();
        if(authorities.size() > 0){
            this.sessionManagedBean.setRole(authorities.get(0).getAuthority());
        }
        CustomUser customUser = (CustomUser) authenticationResponseToken.getPrincipal();
        this.sessionManagedBean.setIdCl(customUser.getIdCl());

        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
        SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy = (SessionAuthenticationStrategy) UtilidadesFaces.getSpringBean("sas");;
        sessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(authenticationResponseToken, httpReq, httpResp);
    } catch (BadCredentialsException badCredentialsException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.badCredentialsException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    } catch (AuthenticationServiceException badCredentialsException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.badCredentialsException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    } catch (LockedException lockedException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.lockedException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
        UtilidadesFaces.addMessage(null, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "login.error.disabledException", this.sessionManagedBean.getActualLanguage());
    }

    return authenticationResponseToken;
}
```